# MSVC C++ compiler option to prevent replacing LF by CR LF in ostream/ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, line-breaks, line-endings

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017's command line tools such as `cl.exe` to compile C++ codes.

Instructions to output line breaks like

```
std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << "abc" << '\n';
```

or

```
printf("abc\n");
```

result in `"abc\r\n"` instead of `"abc\n"`.
How can I change this behavior to get `"abc\n"` output?

If possible, I want it to be realized without making a big change to the core C++ source code like adding "binary mode" flag to everywhere an output stream is created. (I already have a relatively large C++ project which is fine with GCC and trying to build it with MSVC)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve this with Standard C++. Apparently there's no way to achieve this with implementation specific documented functions. If it is possible, it will rely on implementation details.

---

You may hook CRT functions `fopen`, `_wfopen`, `fopen_s`, `wfopen_s`, in hooked function you would alter open mode. C++ streams internally use those functions as well.

How exactly to do it will depend on whether you link CRT statically or dynamically and which version of Visual Studio you use.

Comment: "C++ streams internally use those functions as well" -- maybe, but that's an implementation detail, not a requirement.

Comment: @PeteBecker, sure. There's no documented way to achieve the asked, so have to use implementation details.

Comment: "There's no way to achieve this with Standard C++"
- I don't think there is anything "standard" about the compiler inserting '\r' into the output stream.  I think the OP has a valid request.

Comment: @beevis **the compiler doesn't insert that**, the conversion is all done by the C standard library. The OP writes non-standard code and hence it's invalid to require something like that in a standard-conforming compiler. Check the [compiler assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/EbY485dPz), do you see any `'\r'` in the string???

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be realized without making a big change to the core C++ source code like adding "binary mode" flag to everywhere an output stream is created.

There's no correct way other than fixing your buggy code. There shouldn't be a lot of places that open files so just fix that manually. You don't open tens of thousands of files at a time, do you?

That said, if you really want to use LF everywhere in the C++ streams then the [Microsoft STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL) is open source. You can download the STL, [patch it](https://github.com/microsoft/STL#how-to-build-with-the-visual-studio-ide) and use that one instead of the shipped version in MSVC. The C standard libraries aren't open sourced so you'll have to fix the C part manually, if any

However even if you patch the STL, the source code or the output binary to make it always use LF instead of CRLF then lots of other functionalities will fail, for example console output won't work properly. This is also highly fragile because new code or new 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries added in the future might break because they don't expect LF, so beware of that

> I already have a relatively large C++ project which is fine with GCC and trying to build it with MSVC

Line ending has nothing to do with the compiler. Even if you build with GCC on Windows then it'll still use CRLF. It's a platform property

Comment: His code isn't buggy.  The compiler should not be inserting '\r' characters behind his back.

Comment: @beevis your code is buggy too. Did you even understand the standard. It's the bad programmers who use text mode for those and blame the compiler. On Mac classic the compiler will convert `'\n'` to `'\r'` and maybe you'll say that's wonderful. The standard ensures that `'\n'` in the source code always prints out a new line regardless of the new line in **text mode** in the system in which there are [tons of representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)

Comment: @beevis And **it's not even the compiler, it's the C standard library who does this**. You can compile a freestanding program without the stdlib and free to do whatever you want. I already mentioned the STL and stdlib but it seems you didn't read my answer. You can use gcc or any other compilers and the stdlib still convert `'\n'` to the platform native newline

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent this via [_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/tw4k6df8(v=vs.100)) which you can call at the beginning of your program (watch out for global constructors which might already print something):

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif

int main() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
#endif
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but this only affects stdout and not all the streams including file streams as the OP wants ("everywhere an output stream is created"). Any files opened by `ofstream` won't be affected

Comment: He only used cout and printf in his examples, so it wasn't clear to me what he meant by "output stream".

Comment: please read the title, it's clear that all streams including filestreams need to be changed